# Correlated subquery not working in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza, correlated-subquery

I have a query like this in Netezza, but not sure how I can rewrite it so it will work. Thanks

```
with dates as (
      select distinct event_date from table
     )
select event_date, 
       (select count(distinct id)
        from table 
        where event_date < dates.event_date
       )
from dates
```

```
This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and expected result

Comment: It also helps if you explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be more efficient using window functions anyway.  I think the logic is:

```
select event_date, 
       sum(count(*)) over (order by event_date) - count(*) as events_before
from table
group by event_date
```